# Flexible enums in C++

Tags: c++, enums, enumeration

How can I organize enums so that each enum entry could have parameters, like I can do in Haxe, for instance:

```
enum GraphicAct {
  ClearScreen; 
  MoveTo(x:Float, y:Float);
  LineTo(x:Float, y:Float);
  FillColor(color:Int);
  EndFill;
}

function main(){
  var actions:Array<GraphicAct>;
  actions.push(ClearScreen);
  actions.push(FillColor(0xaaffff));
  actions.push(MoveTo(100, 100));
  actions.push(LineTo(200, 100));
  actions.push(LineTo(100, 200));
  actions.push(EndFill);


  for(act in actions){
    switch(act){
       case ClearScreen: // do clear screen here...
       case MoveTo(x, y): // move position
       case LineTo(x, y): // move position
    }
  }
}
```

As far as I know, C++ supports only enum entries without parameters, like "ClearScreen" and "EndFill", but in this case how do I organize commands sequences in C++, like I did in example with graphic commands?

Comment: why do you want it as an enum? you could get what you want with a `GraphicsAct` base class and then using polymorphism

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may use `union` and `enum`, something like:

```
enum class EGraphicActType
{
    ClearScreen, MoveTo, LineTo, FillColorData, EnfFillData
};

struct ClearScreenData {};
struct MoveToData { float x; float y;};
struct LineToData { float x; float y;};
struct FillColorData { Int color;};
struct EnfFillData {};

struct GraphicAct {
    EGraphicActType type;
    union
    {
        ClearScreenData clearScreenData;
        MoveToData moveToData;
        LineToData lineToData;
        FillColorData fillColorData;
        EnfFillData endFillData;
    } data;
};
```

If you have access to boost, you may use `boost::variant`.

Answer (score -1):

For this purpose c++ offers structs and classes. A c++ enum is a specific value out of a set of predefined values.

Edit: Here's an example of a possible solution

```
class Action {
 public:
  doAction();
}

class ClearScreen : public class Action {
 public:
  doAction() {
   // do something
  }
}

class MoveTo : public class Action {
 public:
  int x, y;

  doAction() {
   // do something
  }
}

// Etc for other things you want to do;

int main() {
  std::vector<Action> Actions;
  ClearScreen clr;
  Actions.push_back(clr);
  MoveTo move;
  move.x = 100;
  move.y = 100;
  Actions.push_back(move);

 for (Action a:Actions) {
   a.doAction();
 }
}
```

Sorry, I'm just on the road and can't check if the code really works, but i think you should get the idea.

Comment: That doesn't answer the question or provide a solution. This should be a comment instead of an answer.

Comment: Correct. I added the example